# Open Communication With Serial Port throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, printing, ports

I am trying to open communication with Com port 3, where is my printer connected. I would like to send commands from C# application directly to printer(emmulation commands) in order to check printer status. Printer is connected to my machine via Usb-To-Serial cable on COM3.

But when I try to open port I get ArgumentException - The port name does not begin with "COM". - or -The file type of the port is not supported.

When I go to device manager I can see printer driver and Usb driver set to same COM3, baud rate = 115200, Parity = none, DataBits = 8, StopBits = 1

Here is my code:

```
var printerPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
if(printerPort.IsOpen)
{
    printerPort.Close();
}
printerPort.ReadTimeout = 1400;
printerPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
printerPort.Open();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if removing the Close() statement solves issue.  When you close the object it is disposing the object so you would need to call the new method again.

Comment: I just tried it. No luck :(
"The given port name does not start with COM/com or does not resolve to a valid serial port.\r\nParameter name: portName"}

Comment: The error doesn't make a lot of sense.  The code an find pott and close it, but then cannot open it.  I think the operating system owns the port and is not really closing the port. So I would eliminate the Open() and Close().

Comment: But when I try to send data or anything else I get InvalidOperationException - The port is closed

Comment: Serial ports cannot be shared, probably has something to do with this wonky error message.  You are just doing it wrong, you need to talk to the printer instead of the serial port.  The subject of [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c--net).

Comment: You were right. But still, in this example I can't get response from printer to check it status.